# Extending json_encode for nested objects

Tags: php, object, json

I am using **PHP 5.2.x** and want to encode objects of my custom PHP classes with only private members. One of the private members is an array of objects of another custom class.

I tried the solution outlined in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7005915/17716, but that obviously does not work recursively. The only solution that I can see is extending the json_encode method somehow ,so that the class' version of the json_encode method is called instead of the default method.

For reference, the code is as follows:

```
Class A {
    private $x;
    private $y;
    private $z;
    private $xy;
    private $yz;
    private $zx;

    public function f1() {
        ...
    }

    public function f2() {
        ...
    }
    .
    .
    .
    public function getJSONEncode() {
         return json_encode(get_object_vars($this));
    }
}

class B {

    private $p; //This finally stores objects of class A
    private $q;
    private $r;

    public function __construct() {
            $this->p = array();
    }

    public function fn1() {
        ...
    }

    public function fn2() {
        ...
    }

    .
    .
    .

    public function getJSONEncode() {
         return json_encode(get_object_vars($this));
    }

}

class C {

    private $arr;

    public function __construct() {
            $this->arr = array();
    }

    public function fillData($data) {
        $obj = new B();
        //create objects of class B and fill in values for all variables
        array_push($this->arr, $obj)
    }

    public function returnData() {
          echo $this->arr[0]->getJSONEncode(); //Edited to add

    }

}
```

What would be the best way to achieve this nested json encoding?

Edited to Add:

The output I get when the returnData method is executed is:

```
{"p":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],"q":"Lorem Ipsum","r":"Dolor Sit Amet"}
```

Comment: I don't see any Nested json here .. `Class A { class PostAttributes {` is invalid .. Am not sure i totally get what you want

Comment: Apologies and thanks for catching that.
The "Class PostAttributes {" was a copy paste error. Also added the comment that the array P contains objects of Class A

Comment: what exactly are you executing .. its not in the above code

Comment: Your code formatting is a little off there.

Comment: @Baba: Not sure I understand your question... Can you elaborate?

Comment: The nature of private values is to be private, why would you want them to then translate to a data construct that has no concept of private? Are you expecting to send them back to JavaScript? -- if so, why not use public items instead, considering they will be public eventually?

Comment: @AJ How did get your output ?? what ....

Comment: @pebbl Yes I return it to a frontend for processing by a JS library

Comment: @Baba: Class C->returnData(); //I added an echo statement there for simplicity's purposes. Just assume that returnData is called somewhere

Comment: Ok, So what happens if you stop using private elements and set them to public instead?

Comment: The objects will be encoded. However, I prefer not to make public the properties of the classes merely for encoding. I have additional code which will access data including to and from a DB and prefer to use proper getter and setters for clean access/writes to the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst I believe you would be better off writing a proper export/encode function for each of your classes *(which would construct a public object from both private and public values just for encoding - you could be quite clever and use php's [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) ability)* - instead - you could make use of the following code:

```
/// example class B
class TestB {
  private $value = 123;
}

/// example class A
class TestA {
  private $prop;
  public function __construct(){
    $this->prop = new TestB();
  }
}

function json_encode_private($obj){
  /// export the variable to find the privates
  $exp = var_export($obj, true);
  /// get rid of the __set_state that only works 5.1+
  $exp = preg_replace('/[a-z0-9_]+\:\:__set_state\(/i','((object)', $exp);
  /// rebuild the object
  eval('$enc = json_encode('.$exp.');');
  /// return the encoded value
  return $enc;
}

echo json_encode_private(new TestA());

/// {"prop":{"value":123}}
```

So the above should work, but I wouldn't recommend using `eval` anywhere in php - just because I always hear alarm bells quietly off in the distance :)

### **update**

Just had a thought of what might make this a little safer, rather than using `eval` you could use `create_function` which would limit some of its creational powers, or at least the scope of those powers...

```
function json_encode_private($obj){
  $exp = var_export($obj, true);
  $exp = preg_replace('/[a-z0-9_]+\:\:__set_state\(/i','((object)', $exp);
  $enc = create_function('','return json_encode('.$exp.');');
  return $enc();
}
```

### **update 2**

Had a chance to play around with another way of converting an object with private properties, to an object with public properties - using only a simple function *(and no eval)*. The following would need to be tested on whichever version of PHP you are using as it's behaviour - again - might not be reliable.... due to the weird `\0`*`Class Name`*`\0` prefixing in the converted private properties *(see comments in code)*.

*For more info on this strange prefixing behaviour:

https://www.php.net/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting*

Anyway, so using a test class:

```
class RandomClass {
  private $var = 123;
  private $obj;
  public function __construct(){
    $this->obj = (object) null;
    $this->obj->time = time();
  }
}
```

We can use the following function to convert it to a public object:

```
function private_to_public( $a ){
  /// grab our class, convert our object to array, build our return obj
  $c = get_class( $a ); $b = (array) $a; $d = (object) null;
  /// step each property in the array and move over to the object
  /// usually this would be as simple as casting to an object, however
  /// my version of php (5.3) seems to do strange things to private 
  /// properties when casting to an array... hence the code below:
  foreach( $b as $k => $v ){
    /// for some reason private methods are prefixed with a \0 character
    /// and then the classname, followed by \0 before the actual key value. 
    /// This must be some kind of internal protection causing private  
    /// properties to be ignored. \0 is used by some languges to terminate  
    /// strings (not php though, as far as i'm aware).
    if ( ord($k{0}) === 0 ) {
      /// trim off the prefixed weirdnesss..?!
      $e = substr($k, 1 + strlen($c) + 1);
      /// unset the $k var first because it will remember the \0 even 
      /// if other values are assigned to it later on....?!
      unset($k); $k = $e;
    }
    /// so if we have a key, either public or private - set our value on
    /// the destination object.
    if ( $k !== '' && $k !== NULL && $k !== FALSE )  {
      $d->{$k} = $v;
    }
  }
  return $d;
}
```

So if we put it all together:

```
$a = new RandomClass();

echo json_encode( private_to_public( $a ) );

/// {"var":123,"obj":{"time":1349777323}}
```

Again your best / most reliable bet is to either bespokely code your conversion methods for each class, or create some kind of generalised solution using [Class Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php), but that latter is far more involved, more involved than a StackOverflow answer... at least with the amount of time I have free ;)

### **further info**

The above code will work when trying to access objects from anywhere, the reason for implementing this was because my first attempt was obviously to use the following:

```
echo json_encode( get_object_vars($a) );

/// you will get {} which isn't what you expect
```

It seems that if you want to use `get_object_vars` you have to use it from a context that has access to all the properties, i.e. from inside the class you are exposing:

```
public function getAllProperties(){
  return get_object_vars( $this );
}
```

So, imagine we'd added the above to the RandomClass definition:

```
echo json_encode( $a->getAllProperties() );

/// you will get {"var":123,"obj":{"time":1349777323}}
```

This works because the members of a class have access to all the class's properties public or private.... so as I say, working this way is far far superior; superior, but not always possible.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not entirely familiar with out OO works in PHP, but isn't there anyway that I can extend the json_encode method (or my classes) so that when encoding is tried, they automatically get called? - Something similar to what JSONSerialize makes possible but in PHP 5.4 and above

Comment: No, not that I know of, it's thre reason why [JSONSerialize](http://php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php) was created I guess. There are the magic functions `__sleep` and `__wakeup` but they only work for `serialize` and `unserialize`. And there is the magic function `__set_state` but that is for use with `var_export`. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php - just found this other SO question along the same lines too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778020/how-to-control-json-encode-behavior *(no non-hack answers there either)*

Comment: Thank you for the variety of options to workaround this.
I'm also going to try and push my hosting provider to upgrade their version of PHP so that I can use the simpler JSONSerialize interface. Until them, you're answer is the way to go :)

Comment: @AJ. No problem... your question forced me to learn something new about `get_object_vars` so all is good! Yep asking them to upgrade sounds like a plan :) only possible problem to that is php 5.4 was released 2012-03-01 and most hosts that I know of would only ever consider upgrading after a release had been in the wild for a least a year - if not more. If you can get a dedicated server you can do what you like though, although that would work out as rather an expensive json_encode function ;)